# VirtualDocRoute when not all params are present

Tags: apache, vhosts

I've got mass Vhosts set up on our shared hosting box with the following directive in the apache2.conf file:

```
VirtualDocumentRoot /www/hosts/%3+/%2/%1/public
```

So, for example:

```
www.domain.com ==> /www/hosts/com/domain/www/public/
www.domain.co.uk==> /www/hosts/co.uk/domain/www/public/
```

The issue is if the naked domain is pointing at my server, I've no idea where the document route is.

My thinking was :

```
domain.com ==> /www/hosts//com/domain/public/
```

as %3+ matches to nothing (the domain only has 2 elements). However, if I put an index.html file in there to test, it does not appear to be where DocumentRoot is being set.

Any idea's either

a) where DocumentRoot is going to be when a parameter is missing from the VirtualDocumentRoot pattern

or

b) how to set a different VirtualDocumentRoot if only 2 parts of the domain are present (ignoring 2 part TLD's such as ".co.uk" grrrrr)

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html#interpol) say

> If N or M  *[those being the numbers in a %N.M interpolation term]* is greater than the number of parts available a single underscore is interpolated.

so maybe try `/www/hosts/_/com/domain/public/`.

Comment: That's exactly where it is! Thanks 1e6 Ulrich - I completely missed that one liner in the docs :(

Comment: Glad it worked, @TimShields. (You can mark answers as useful / solving your problem with the up arrow / the green checkmark, respectively.)